# how do I redirect user to a page if user is logged in

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've tried using useEffect on `/dashboard` to check if user is loggedIn, but it display dashboard messages before redirecting user back into `/login` page.

`/dashboard`

```
function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <div>
            This is Dashboard page.
        </div>
    );

}

export default Dashboard;
```

`/login`

```
   const login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.message) {
                setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
            } else {
                setLoginStatus(response.data[0].username)
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login").then((response) => {
            if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
                setLoginStatus(response.data.user[0].username);
                history.push("/dashboard");
            }
        })
    }, [])
```

`server.js`

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user })
    } else {
        res.send({ loggedIn: false })
    }
})

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?;", [username],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({ err: err });
            }

            if (result.length > 0) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (err, response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        req.session.user = result;
                        console.log(req.session.user)
                        res.send(result)
                    } else {
                        res.send({ message: "Wrong username/password!" });
                    }
                })
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "User doesn't exist" });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: If you are not using redux, you can pass the login status as a prop to your Dashboard component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your main component with an AuthContext with your current auth data, so you will have it available in the whole elements tree

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this. But here is a well written blogpost on that matter: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications?ck_subscriber_id=1244176450

The basic gist is that you would save the user data into a context when you get a response from /login. Then in some component, whether it is a parent component or a route component, you would check on that user data and depending on logged in or not, you would render the appropriate page.

In your example you only check if the user is logged in at the first render of your login page (thats how useEffect behaves if the dependency list is empty). So it's checked on first render but not again when the user clicks the login button, so your history push probably never executes.

Another Problem is that your dashboard page is not protected. So your page would render if a user navigates directly to that page.

Answer (score 0):

you should use result.render() function to move user to home page.